# make pdf report based on selected columns from mysql (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, report, fpdf

I've been searching for easier method for generating fpdf report based on selected columns from mysql. Example:

```
   _________________________________________________________
   |NO |NAME    |   COMPANY   |    ADDRESS    |   PHONE    |
   |-------------------------------------------------------|
   | 1 | Andrew |    AT&T     |   123 Street  |    123456  |
   | 2 | Darwin |   Verizon   |   888 Road    |    222222  |
   |___|________|_____________|_______________|____________|
```

I've made forms that include checkboxes so user can select which columns he/she wants to generate like :

```
[] Name
[] Company
[] Address
[] Phone
```

Now here's my initial code if i want to display Name and Company :

```
if(isset($_POST['Name'])){

    if(isset($_POST['Company'])){

        (I copied the code below and pasted here, then I added: 
            $this->Cell(6,1,'Company','TB',0,'L',1); in //HEADER

            $cell[$i][2]=$d[2]; in //ARRAY

            $pdf->Cell(6,1,$cell[$j][1],'B',0,'L'); in //PDF
        )
    }

    class PDF extends FPDF{
        //HEADER
        function Header(){
            $this->SetTextColor(128,0,0); 
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B','8'); 
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B','7');
            $this->SetFillColor(192,192,192); 
            $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0); 
            $this->Cell(1,1,'No','TB',0,'L',1); 
            $this->Cell(5,1,'Name','TB',0,'L',1); 

            $this->Ln();
        }
    }
        $net = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $data);
        if($net->connect_error){
            die("Connection: ".$net->connect_error);
        }

        $q = "select * from people where name between 'Andrew' and 'Darwin'";
        $h = $net->query($q) or die($net->error);
        $i = 0;
        //ARRAY
        while($d=$h->fetch_array()){
            $cell[$i][0]=$d[0];
            $cell[$i][1]=$d[1];

            $i++;
        }
        //PDF
        $pdf = new PDF('L','cm','A4');
        $pdf->Open();
        $pdf->AliasNbPages();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','','6');
        for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++){
            $pdf->Cell(1,1,$j+1,'B',0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(5,1,$cell[$j][0],'B',0,'L');

            $pdf->Ln();
        }   
    $pdf->Output();
}
```

The output will be like:

```
   ____________________________
   |NO |NAME    |   COMPANY   |
   |--------------------------|
   | 1 | Andrew |    AT&T     |
   | 2 | Darwin |   Verizon   |
   |___|________|_____________|
```

As you can see I'm using nested if method, I would like to know if there is any efficient and easier way to do this, because I have more than 10 columns in my real table, which is so much pain if i still use nested if.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are asking but it might be this:

```
for(loop){
    if (isset($_POST['Name'])) {
       $pdf->Cell(Name);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['Company'])) {
       $pdf->Cell(Company);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['Address'])) {
        $pdf->Cell(Address);
    }
    etc etc
    $pdf->Ln();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, what I'm asking is if there is more efficient method to generate specific columns only, so there will be more space in pdf page. if I display all columns, even in landscape, the space won't be enough because some columns has record length that is more than 100 characters. If i use my old code, there will be >4000 lines total which is totally inconvenient.

by the way, could I also use your method to //Header and //Array ?

Comment: But that is what I have done. If a column is checked in the POST it will display it. Do the same for headings.